# add widget in Mainwindow without "gridlayout"

Tags: qt, grid-layout

I create a class that inherits from `QWidget` and add an object of it into a `QGridLayout`.

But it doesn't get shown in it, I connect a `QTimer` object with the function `moveZ()` and it doesn't move in the `QGridLayout`.

This is the function:

```
void mamoli:: moveZ(){
    zmb->show();
    this->setGeometry(this->x()-3,this->y(),50,50);

}
```

Comment: If you need custom widget placement - then do not use layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `QGridLayout` do the following:

```
YourWidget *widget = new YourWidget(QMainWindow *parent);
```

To place your widget inside QMainWidget you should reimplement it's `resizeEvent()` and put your code there. It is also possible then to modify widget's position with `QTimer::timeout()` signal